# When do i use the python decorator function @cache

Tags: python-3.x, caching

Python provides a decorator function @cache that helps cache the output of a function. Which means that if the function is called twice with same arguments,the second time around, the calculation will be skipped and the results will be served from cache.

But I can easily store the results of the calculation in a data structure and use that data structure the second time around. Because the data structure will be alive and not garbage collected until the session ends.

So why do i need @cache

Comment: Yes, you can, but you would simply be re-implementing the `@cache` decorator. It's a convenience built-in: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L479

Comment: It's mostly a matter of convenience and of reducing the amount of explicit code that you write and maintain. Why write explicit code if can avoid it?